# Disable Specific Dates in DatePicker Based on php Result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am trying to disable already selected dates based on mysql query using php
I got the php result in javascript variable (var disabledDate).
Here is my code:

```
    $(function () { 
      $('#school').change(function(){ // this is dropdown
          var dis_date;
            var id = $(this).val();
            var dis_date;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "details.php",
            data: "pass_id="+id,
            success: success
        });
     function success(data) //data received here is ["2020/12/20","2020/12/19"]
    {   
        var disabledDate = data.trim();
        alert(disabledDate);
            jQuery(function() 
            {       
                var date = new Date();
                var currentMonth = date.getMonth();
                var currentDate = date.getDate();
                var currentYear = date.getFullYear();

            $('#calender').datepicker
            ({
                beforeShowDay:before,
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                minDate: new Date(currentYear, 11, 1),
                disabledDates: disabledDate,
                maxDate: new Date(currentYear, 12, 31)
            });
        });
         var before=   function(dt)
         {
            return [dt.getDay() === 0 || dt.getDay() === 6, ""];
         }
    }
     });
    });
```

Unable to disable the dates in datepicker.Any Help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this.

Put the dates that you are fetching from database into array like this.

```
var array = ["2020/12/20","2020/12/19"]
```

and then code like this.

```
$('#calender').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
    }
});
```

check the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CxNNh/2201/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply .i tried this i got this error Cannot read property 'formatDate' of undefined.(even i tried with giving input manually ) :(

Comment: In beforeShowDay already i tried to show only the weekends